# Calling Objective-C method from C++ function?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I picked this up from an answer to a question on how to call objective-c method from C++ method

This runs fine.

**MyObject-C-Interface.h**

```
 #ifndef __MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H__
 #define __MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H__ 1

 int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *myObjectInstance, void *parameter);

 #endif
```

**MyObject.h**

```
#import "MyObject-C-Interface.h"

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
     int someVar;
}

- (int) doSomethingWith:(void *) aParameter;
@end
```

**MyObject.mm**

```
 #import "MyObject.h"

 @implementation MyObject

 int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *self, void *aParameter)
 {
     return [(id) self doSomethingWith:aParameter];
 }

 - (int) doSomethingWith:(void *) aParameter
 {
     // ... some code
     return 1;
 }

 @end
```

**MyCPPClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyCPPClass.h"
#include "MyObject-C-Interface.h"

int MyCPPClass::someMethod (void *objectiveCObject, void *aParameter)
{
     return MyObjectDoSomethingWith (objectiveCObject, aParameter);
}
```

**NOW** if i use something like

**MyObject-C-Interface.h**

```
 #ifndef __MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H__
 #define __MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H__ 1

 @class MyObject;

 int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (MyObject* myObjectInstance, void *parameter);

 #endif
```

My question is instead of using **void *myObjectInstance** if i use **MyObject *myObjectInstance**.

it gives this error 
 **error: expected unqualified-id [1]** : @class line and 
 **error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyObject' [3]** in function prototype's line

Help!!!!

Comment: please check this [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14340)

Comment: Basically, just move MyObjectDoSomethingWith out of the MyObject @implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Link Error:**

The link error is to do with the way C++ mangles function names, which C doesn't do. This actually has nothing to do with Objective-C. Specifically,

```
int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *myObjectInstance, void *parameter);
```

in C or Objective-C (on OSX) is exported to the linker using the name `_MyObjectDoSomethingWith`. A function with the same name and prototype, compiled with a C++ or Objective-C++ compiler, is known to the linker as `__Z23MyObjectDoSomethingWithPvS_`. This is called "name mangling", and it encodes the parameter types. Otherwise, function overloading wouldn't work, as functions with different parameter types but the same name couldn't be distinguished. To call a function defined in C from C++, you therefore have to mark the prototype such that C linkage is expected, and it won't mangle the name of that specific overload of the function.

You'll need to tell the C++ compiler to treat it as a C function using `extern "C"`, either like this:

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H
#define MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *myObjectInstance, void *parameter);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

or like this:

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H
#define MYOBJECT_C_INTERFACE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define CFUN extern "C"
#else
#define CFUN
#endif

CFUN int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *myObjectInstance, void *parameter);

#endif
```

**@class declaration compile error (*please do not ask more than one question at a time*):**

You're trying to `#include "MyObject-C-Interface.h"`, which contains an Objective-C `@class` forward declaration, from **MyCPPClass.cpp**, which will be compiled as pure C++. Objective-C directives are mostly syntax errors in C++, so you can't do that. To pass around Objective-C objects in pure C++ or C, you will need to use the `id` type. You'll need to `#include <objc/objc.h>` for that, as `id` isn't defined by default in C or C++.

*Also, please don't prefix your names with two underscores: __ - such names are reserved.*

Comment: thanks for that but instead of id and void* can i use name of objective C interface to receive the same object

Comment: Not outside of Objective-C and Objective-C++.

Comment: but .h does not come outside of .m or .mm , if i receive it in MyObject* with #import"MyObject.h" then linker error comes otherwise with void* or id program builds and runs fine.

Comment: also you said it will poison my header  to be used in that way only, but i am defining this function in a .mm therefore it should not give any error but error remains

Comment: furthermore why i need constructs to prevent name mangling because this is a C type declaration and function and objective C works well with C

Comment: @tusharfloyd no, you're including the header from a .cpp file, so you can't use Objective-C in it. I've updated the explanation for the link error. `int MyObjectDoSomethingWith (void *myObjectInstance, void *parameter);` is *NOT* a C function when compiled with a C++ compiler, unless you specifically mark it as such.

Comment: @pmjrdan : thank You so much I have gained good amount of clarity in these 2 days.

Comment: and about not asking morethan one questio at a time : I will be careful about that in future , but questions create questions and so was my case :)